# how to fix the link to the pictures in asp net mvc

Tags: c#, .net

I have question for you. Why are not pictures showing?

The html code generates this:

```
<img src=" ~/Images/pilka195919444.jpg" width="300" height="300">
<img src=" ~/Images/traffic195919452.png" width="300" height="300">
```

and my code looks like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Images)
{
    <img src="@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)" width="300" height="300"/>
}
```

```
                    if (item != null && item.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        if (Path.GetExtension(item.FileName).ToLower() == ".gif"
                            || Path.GetExtension(item.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpg"
                            || Path.GetExtension(item.FileName).ToLower() == ".png"
                            || Path.GetExtension(item.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpeg"
                            )
                        {
                            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item.FileName);
                            string extension = Path.GetExtension(item.FileName);
                            fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;


                            ImagesProducts images = new ImagesProducts();
                            images.ProductId = vm.Product.ProductId;
                            images.ImagePath = " ~/Images/" + fileName;
                            db.ImagesProducts.Add(images);
                            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Try saving your `ImagePath` as: `images.ImagePath= Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"/Images/", file.FileName)`;

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can generate the `ImagePath` as:

```
images.ImagePath= Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"/Images/", fileName)
```

This would give you the path of the current directory where the `Images` folder resides.